# Select values with multiple limits

Tags: mysql, sql, database

From the items table i need to select 10 items belongs to category1,5 items belongs to category2,and 2 items belongs to category3.

Is there a way to select the values in a single query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically not really one select ...

```
( SELECT * FROM items WHERE belongs_to='category1' LIMIT 10 )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM items WHERE belongs_to='category2' LIMIT 5 )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM items WHERE belongs_to='category3' LIMIT 2 )
```

Edit: Added braces (see comment).

Comment: Thanks it works for me with a small change
SELECT * FROM items WHERE belongs_to='category1' LIMIT 10
UNION
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE belongs_to='category2' LIMIT 5)
With out the parenthesis it is taking the limit of the last query

Comment: Is there any other way to get the result??I am just curious!!

Comment: @Damodaran You are right, I forgot the braces. I don't know any other way to get your desired result.